# extending a form's height to fit the content in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is a simple CSS question but I just cannot find it anywhere and the methods I've used on similar questions just never work. How do I a automatically/dynamically change a form's height when content is added in the form in HTML, CSS or JavaScript? And please, I'm not saying putting a scroll bar on the form using overflow: auto; I want it to scroll using the browser's main window. I don't want the content in the form to get out of the boundary of the form. But it would be a relief if only CSS did this. But suggestion is welcome at thus point.

Answer (score 0):

Form is a **block** element. Don't give it an explicit height and it should adjust accordingly to its contents. However, if you are adamant that it should have a certain minimum height then use the **min-height** property and set it to the minimum height.

However, if any of its child elements are have its float property set, then give the form a **clearfix** class.

Comment: sorry for not posting the code but the child element is absolutely positioned in the center of the form. And even with the method you just suggested, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes my method wont work if its absolutely positioned. Although, I doubt using absolute in your case. Please post your html.

Comment: I solved the problem by just changing those child elements from absolute. Turned out well.