# Form height to increase based on content in AngularJs

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a angularJs form, which has multiple controls. When the page loads initially, all the contents fit in the form. When the validation messages are shown, the submit button, cancel button are not shown. These buttons are getting below. 
Below is the code in index.cshtml. I have only put few controls, additional controls are also there.

```
  <body class="ng-cloak">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    <div ng-controller="testController" ng-init="init()">
        <form name="mainForm" id="createForm" ng-submit="mainForm.$valid && add()" novalidate="">       

            <div>
                <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
                <header>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <a class="navbar-brand">Test</a>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-right nav-pills">
                                <li ng-class="{active: createMenu}">
                    <a  href="" ng-click="show('createMenu')">Create</a></li>
                                <li ng-class="{active: dashboardMenu}">
                                    <a href="" ng-click="show('dashboardMenu')"> Dashboard</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </header>
            </div>
            <div class="container" ng-show="createMenu">
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <label class="control-label">Groups:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                        <select name="grpTypeSelect" required="" ng-model="selectedgrpType" class="dropdown form-control cl-sm-6" ng-options="grp.GrpTypeName for grp in grpss" ng-change="updateImageUrl(selectedgrpType)">
                            <option value="">-- Select the Group --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span id="span1" style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.grpTypeSelect.$error.required">Group is required</span>

                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <label>Name :</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <input type="text" maxlength="150" class="input-md form-control col-md-4" required="" ng-model="testName" name="testName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.testName.$error.required">Name is required</span>
                <br />
                <br />

               <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Start date</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group date" id="startDatepicker">
                                <input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" ng-model="defaultStartDate" name="startDate">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.startDate == '' && mainForm.startDate.$error.required">Start Date is required</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label class="control-label">End date</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group date" id="endDatepicker">
                                <input type="text" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" ng-model="defaultEndDate" name="endDate">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.endDate.$error.required">End Date is required</span>
                    </div>

                    <!--/col-->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Start Time</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group" id="startTimepicker">
                                <input type="text" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="00:00 AM/PM" ng-model="defaultStartTime" name="startTime">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.startTime.$error.required">Start Time is required</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label class="control-label">End Time</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group" id="endTimepicker">
                                <input type="text" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="00:00 AM/PM" ng-model="defaultEndTime" name="endTime">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>

                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.endTime.$error.required">End Time is required</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6">

                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submitted=true" class="btn btn-primary" /> 
                            <input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Cancel" ng-click="reset()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Is it possible to fit the contents even during the validation messages are shown? i am not setting any specific class to set height. How to make sure that submit and cancel button are also visible, when the form height increases. I checked this link [extending a form's height to fit the content in the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164113/extending-a-forms-height-to-fit-the-content-in-the-form) , but could not find the solution.

Adding the snippet to show the issue:
Initial load shows as : [image]

After error message: [image]
Thanks

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: BTW your code has a missing > after the LI tag here: <li ng-class="{active: createMenu}"<a  href="" ng-click="show('createMenu')">Create</a></li>

Comment: Corrected the "li" tag. I am not able to create a fiddle, as the form size increases only when the error messages are shown.

Comment: try `height: auto` to the form

Comment: Hi. I tried height:auto to the form. same issue. Is the issue in the div containing the date and time controls?

Comment: Is your website public?
Or give a working demo. Can't say anything with just html code

Answer (score 0):

For making anything auto-adjustable according to its content, you can use *min-height* property.

```
min-height:100px;
```

Try this, add it in your *form* css, like this

```
<form name="mainForm" id="createForm" 
      ng-submit="mainForm.$valid && add()" 
      novalidate=""
      style="min-height:100px;">
```

Comment: Hi, I added the min-height, but still the same. I have updated the code to show the additional controls. when the date validation happens, the submit button controls are not being visible.

Comment: Can you create a plunker/fiddle of this, just showing form and validation logic? Because it's hard to re-generate issue without some code.

Comment: I have added a snippet of the issue. I have used bootstrap.css. But still the issue exists